# How can you sort a list of lists by the number of nonzero elements in each sublist?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists (8 lists of 15 elements each) and it's like below:

```
mylist = [
    ['Adam', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'], 
    ['Bobby', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0'], 
    ['Felicia', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'], 
    ['Jake', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
    ['MikeP', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
    ['MikeF', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
    ['Shannon', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
    ['Tom', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0']
]
```

Using Python 3, I'm trying to get `mylist` sorted beginning with the most zeros in a sublist to the fewest zeros in a sublist.  I don't want to sort within each list - the 0s and 1s need to stay where they are ultimately.

I have tried using `len()` and lambda functions and other ideas I find here like breaking it down with the following:

```py
for index1, value1 in enumerate(mylist):
    mylistsorted.append([value2 for index2, value2 in enumerate(mylist[index1]) if value2 != '0'])

mylistsorted.sort(key = len)
```

But I lose all the '0's of course in that new sorted list. Should this perhaps be done with something else like numpy or matrices or something else vice lists of lists? Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list.count` as your key for sorted to count all the 0's in each list:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: -x[1:].count('0'))
```

Comment: "beginning with the most zeros in a sublist to the fewest zeros in a sublist"

Comment: Hmmm, not working for me ... I will keep playing with it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you both. In 5 minutes you helped me accomplish what i was spending hours on trying to figure out myself (and learning). For clarification though, can one of you explain the '-' before the x and l in your codes? Thanks. (Duh - I figured it out - thanks!)

Comment: The original code does not treat the first item differently from the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `key` that counts the number of 0's:

```
mylist.sort( key = lambda l : -l.count('0') )
```

Comment: I'd upvote if it didn't have all those non-standard extra spaces :-P

Comment: Sure; no reason to make it any more legible than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a not-so-wild guess and counting the ones instead:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda l: l.count('1'))
```

Comment: Ha. Actually I just realized that while the question text talks about sorting by zeros, the *title* says sorting by nonzeros.